# Python os.exec on Windows returns control to calling process

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I'm attempting to implement a Python script that will modify the environment, and then execute a command under that new environment. As a start, I've been attempting to leverage `os.execvpe` as in the following example (`envtest.py`):

```py
import os
import sys

def main():
    env = dict(os.environ)
    env["FOO"] = "BAR"
    os.execvpe(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1:], env=env)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This seems to work fine on Linux. For example, if I invoke the script `python envtest.py bash` I get a new bash shell with my extra environment variable set. If I look at the process tree, my new environment is a child of the previous shell, and when I exit control returns to the previous shell. That's the behavior I'm looking for.

On Windows, I'm seeing something different, If I execute `python envtest.py cmd`, I get what looks like that behavior. A new command prompt is spawned with my environment set, however it appears that control was also returned to the parent command prompt. Both command prompts end up active, and they appear to alternate between each other (at least that's the behavior I'm observing). Here's an example interaction that's leading me to that conclusion:

```
C:\Temp>python envtest.py cmd

C:\Temp>Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1217]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Temp>echo %FOO%
%FOO%

C:\Temp>echo %FOO%
BAR

C:\Temp>echo %FOO%
%FOO%

C:\Temp>echo %FOO%
BAR
```

Is there a way to have a python script replace itself with another process without also returning control to the parent process on Windows? Alteratively is there a way for a python script to spawn a child process and exit, where the child process is a child of the python script's parent, i.e. the resulting process tree would look like:

```
cmd.exe
\_ cmd.exe
```

Instead of:

```
cmd.exe
\_ python.exe
   \_ cmd.exe
```

Comment: All programmers know if you want to shell you have to wait.

Comment: Windows has no support for the Unix `exec` family of functions that replace the current process image. The C runtime's `exec*` functions simply fake it by spawning a child process and terminating the current process, which is practically useless because the shell is waiting on the terminated process. Don't use `exec*` in Windows; it's practically never what you want. This means in Windows you can only create a spawn-based launcher that waits on the child and proxies its exit status. It's best to set the child in a kill-on-close Job object, like py.exe does when it runs python.exe.